# How can I find an replace an array value based on another value in the same multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace

So I have a multidimensional array like the one below:

```
[0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => 110
    ["list"] => {}
    ["MainProduct"] => 2         <- Step2: Replace the 2 with a 5 where productName is Oranges
    ["productName"] => Oranges   <- Step1: Find where we have "Oranges"
  }
[1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => 111
    ["list"] => {}
    ["MainProduct"] => 110
    ["productName"] => Apples
  }
```

Ultimately, what I need to achieve is to find were the `value` for `key` productName equals `Oranges` and based on that to replace the `value` for `key` MainProduct in the same sub array.

I thought I should first find the index for the array containing `Oranges` and then replace the `value` for `key` mainProduct but can't seem to do it properly.
They `key` names are always the same, while the `value` names are different.

Also, the array is dynamic so the array with `Oranges` won't always have the same index.

This is the desired result:

```
[0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => 110
    ["list"] => {}
    ["MainProduct"] => 5         <- This is changed to 5 where productName is "Oranges"
    ["productName"] => Oranges   
  }
[1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => 111
    ["list"] => {}
    ["MainProduct"] => 110
    ["productName"] => Apples
  }
```

Comment: Is `productName` unique, meaning you wouldn't have two entries for `Oranges`?

Comment: Why does 2 magically become 5? I do not find this [mcve] or question to be clear.

Comment: @Abra can you explain this question to me? Is this just another duplicate of how to search a column of a 2d array ...and then [do something] with the row?

Comment: Please provide a larger and more challenging sample data set so that your logical goal is more clear.  I fear your [mcve] is too small to represent the scope of your task. @BradG  Right now, it seems that you have a parent-child relationship.  Might parents have multiple children?  Might there be grandchildren?  What might those results look like? Might your data look [like this](https://3v4l.org/uLLMG)? We cannot know for sure unless you tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variant of the strategy you proposed:

```
<?php
$data = [
  [
    "id" => 110,
    "MainProduct" => 2,
    "productName" => "Oranges",
  ],
  [
    "id" => 111,
    "MainProduct" => 110,
    "productName" => "Apples",
  ]
];

$output = [];
array_walk($data, function(&$entry) use($data)  {
  $mainProduct = array_search($entry['MainProduct'], $data);
  $entry['productName'] = $data[$mainProduct]['productName'];
});

print_r($data);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 110
            [MainProduct] => 2
            [productName] => Oranges
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 111
            [MainProduct] => 110
            [productName] => Oranges
        )
)
```

Comment: You need to add a condition to the second pass where you react when the map does _not_ contain the main product.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the keys and combine with the `productName` values, then you can search it and get the key.  Then use the key to update `MainProduct`:

```
$array[array_search('Oranges', array_combine(array_keys($array), array_column($array, 'productName')))]['MainProduct'] = 5;
```

If `productName` is unique, then I would just modify the array to index on that:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'productName');
$array['Orange']['MainProduct'] = 5;
```

Comment: If updating a column value in a qualifying row is what is required, then only one loop should be used.  https://3v4l.org/Rq26t  We already have pages like this.